# jQuery dragging nested list items

Tags: jquery, list, nested, draggable

I have this unordered list with a nested list and using jQuery UI Draggable to drag the top list item that has the nest unordered list inside it.

```
    <ul class="data-item_wrapper">

    <li>

      <ul class="row-data">

        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>

      </ul>

    </li>
    <li>

      <ul class="row-data">

        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test</li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    </ul>
```

I am not sure if it is the jQuery Draggable function that I am using that is not working correctly or maybe my trigger is incorrect.

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {              
        $(".data-item_wrapper li").draggable();
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you added references properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function() {              
    $(".data-item_wrapper>li").draggable();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hP5Jp/1/)

it will only select the direct child of `ul`,otherwise it select the nested child also..

Comment: I tried that. I think it could be a problem with my css maybe and its not responding to the jQuery function properly.

Comment: Yip. Thats correct. It worked. I think it was something with the editor I was using. But it worked perfectly when I implemented it in the document. Thanks for the help.